# Django model: Get many fields from 2 tables on same foreign key

Tags: django-models, django-queryset

I have 2 model classes in Django:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
 receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
 content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
 object_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 type = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

Class Notification stores notification about users activity. Field "content" is like: "welcome you registered Business Course successfully", or "5ASC is your voucher code". Field type stores types of object: course, promotion.

```
class PaymentTransaction(models.Model):
 course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
 student = models.ForeignKey(User)
 PAYMENT_STATUS = ( SUCCESS, FAILURE, PROCESSING)
 payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PAYMENT_STATUS, default=PROCESSING)
```

In notification pop up, when he clicks to paid Course then go to Course detail page and start learning, when he clicks to unpaid Course then go to Course register page, when he clicks to promotion code then go to promotion code page

How to have a QuerySet return all fields of Notification and PaymentTransaction tables, and condition is Notification.receiver_id = PaymentTransaction.student_id .
For each Course notification, i want to get Course payment status.I did:

`user = request.user
 p_list = PaymentTransaction.objects.filter(student=user)
 n_list = Notification.objects.filter(receiver=user).intersection(p_list)`

But it did't work

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you create the Models like this but:
I think it should be:

```
class Book:
      title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
      price = models.FloatField()
class User:
      name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
      something = models.CharField()
class Book_User:
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)
      book = models.ForeignKey(User)
      detail = models.CharField()
```

And i what is noti for?Just show up the list?
~> it should be the list of Book_User in page of user
~> Problem solve

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i dont want to add more tables to my database. I also change my tables to explain my question more specifically

Comment: Can't get your purpose when use Noti with just 1 FK to User...
It just make you know this noti for whom. So how the hell this noti link to Payment??? It can't match each other.
It just so you which user have this noti and who have to pay
If you want to resolve it:
Show pop-up in Course'page and set the Action: Click for Pay, Unpay,... and you can get MORE INFO via this page (get the id of course)